# How do I refer the current namespace while declaring it? Is there any word like "self"/"this"?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Here if I rename the namespace I must also remember to look at the rest of the code, and do all necessary changes. Is there any word like `self`, `this` or `current` to refer to current namespace?

```
namespace myNamespace {
  int myInt;
  void myFunc() {
    myNamespace::myInt = 66;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Why are you reffering to your current namespace? there is no need to for that, you can easily write:

```
namespace myNamespace {
  int myInt = 33;
  void myFunc() {
    myInt = 33;
  }
};
```

No matter what variables are declared out there (such as a global `myInt`), variables of this scope will be used by default.

However if you want to rename, you can use IDE techniques like replace or refactor.

Answer (score 22):

No, there isn't, but if you really want to do something like that you could fake it.

```
namespace myNamespace {
  namespace _ns = ::myNamespace;
  int myInt;
  void myFunc() {
    _ns::myInt = 66;
  }
}
```

If you change `myNamespace`, you need only change `_ns` to match it.

Also, the semicolon following the namespace is superfluous.

Comment: I always forget about namespace assignment! That's a trick I need to remember.

Answer (score 18):

Good question. No, there is nothing like this.

Furthermore, pay attention that `myNamespace::myInt` isn’t even unambiguous in the case of nested namespaces (say you’ve got the convoluted case of `namespace myNamespace { namespace myNamespace { … } }`. To be on the safe side you need to use the fully qualified namespace:

```
::myNamespace::myInt = 33;
```

Where the prefixed `::` refers to the global namespace.